# Mongoose saves schema to different collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If I create a Schema for a Person in mongoose, I'd do it like this:

```
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
                                             name: String,
                                             age: Number
                                         });
const Person = mongoose.model("Person", personSchema);

const person = new Person({
                              name: "Joe",
                              age: 28
                          });

person.save();
```

Now, at some earlier point in my code, the model was named "People" instead of "Person".
But if this is all the code I am running, how does mongoose know that I do not want to create a new schema ?

My mongodb via shell looks like this:

```
> show collections
fruits
people
```

And

```
> db.people.find()
```

returns nothing, it is empty atm.

Now running my code above, the following happens:

```
> db.people.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5dd691e59fe1c40a82f6fbde"), "name" : "Joe", "age" : 28, "__v" : 0 }
```

Why does this get saved in my "people" collection, instead of creating a new collection for "person" ?
Nowhere do I reference this people collection in the code anymore.

Comment: mongoose pluralize the collection name, so person becomes people. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection

Comment: wow, I am dumb. I knew of the singular/plural thing, but as non native speaker I just assumed they add the plural "s"  like fruit-->fruits, it has not occured to me that people is the plural of person,  i expected to see Persons..oh my..